# How to save the content of many dictionaries to one dictionary and then save it in a list in for-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, dictionary

The code below is running well. I would like to know if there is a possibility to run the same code in a few number of line codes (lines) through saving the content in only one dictionary, for example (mhist) and then save the content of that dictionary in one list in for-loop.
This is my code:

```
fn = 'screenviewclean.1.csv'

f = open(fn,"r")

reader = csv.reader(f)

n = 0

i=0 

mhist = {}

mhist1 = {}

mhist2 = {}

mhist3 = {}

mhist4 = {}


for line in reader:   
    
        i+=1
        
        sec= line [10]
        IpAddress = line [2]
        timeStamp = line [6]
        time = timeStamp[11:13]+ timeStamp[13:19]
        Day =  timeStamp[0:10]
        
        if i>1:
            if float(line[10]) <= float(21600):
                if IpAddress in mhist.keys():
                    mhist[IpAddress].append(str(time))
                else:
                    mhist[IpAddress] = [str (time)]
                    
            if float(line[10]) > float(21600) and float(line[10]) <= float(43200) :
                if IpAddress in mhist1.keys():
                    mhist1[IpAddress].append(str(time))
                else:
                    mhist1[IpAddress] = [str (time)]
                    
            if float(line[10]) > float(43200) and float(line[10]) <= float(64800) :
                if IpAddress in mhist2.keys():
                    mhist2[IpAddress].append(str(time))
                else:
                    mhist2[IpAddress] = [str (time)]
                    
            if float(line[10]) > float(64800) and float(line[10]) <= float(86400) :
                if IpAddress in mhist3.keys():
                    mhist3[IpAddress].append(str(time))
                else:
                    mhist3[IpAddress] = [str (time)]
                    
            if float(line[10]) > float(86400) and float(line[10]) <= float(108000) :
                if IpAddress in mhist4.keys():
                    mhist4[IpAddress].append(str(time))
                else:
                    mhist4[IpAddress] = [str (time)]

        n+=1  

print (mhist)

print (mhist1)

print (mhist2)

print (mhist3)

print (mhist4)
```

This is two lines of the dataset which I have:

Unnamed: 0 lastLoggedVersion IpAddress deviceId deviceOS userId timeStamp screenName userType doc.id seconds

0 1.6.0.1 192.168.0.77 7612F62D-E392-4269-B49B-4F1214AA3888 iOS13.6.1 5U1XW8wkoqUPCTGhC1ni9Whinvt1 2020-11-13 22:28:55.029000+00:00 StudentProfile student 00mrvPyS9Y2Al9iTN1vw 1231534.547

2 1.6.1.44 10.0.2.16 40a4dc7cb837fdec Android10 27lFw6EnfbYFsU3F8AEejYGQRRl1 2020-11-12 21:28:00.998000+00:00 CompanySettings company 01dMOvAgsRTPSWXTDXIh 1141480.516

Comment: How exactly do you intend to save the `dictionary` as a `List`? The `dictionary` associates a value to each key in the dictionary. Saving the `dictionary` as a `List` implies you will lose this association (of each IP address to a timestamp) unless you don't care about this association. Are you just going to place every value in the `dictionary` in the `List`?

Comment: I am sorry for confusion. I am looking to create many dictionaries where each dictionary has many ip-addresses (as keys) and many values for each dictionary (for example: '192.168.1.240': ['16:23:40', '16:23:39', '16:23:20']) after that I am looking to save those dictionarries into a a list of dictionaries in few line codes. This is an example to what I am looking for [{''192.168.1.240': ['16:23:40', '16:23:39', '16:23:20'], '192.168.0.242': ['20:14:07', '20:14:09']}].

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That makes sense now. I will work on a solution for you.

Comment: Also, are your dictionaries working properly when you print them at the end? Like with the values/data that you expect? I want to make sure the dictionaries are conforming to your expectations first.

Comment: Yes, all of them working properly when I print them at the end.

Comment: Also, I would like to inform you that I made filtration of the data every 6 hours, for example, for if float(line[10]) > float(21600) and float(line[10]) <= float(43200), I made filtration from 6 hours (6*60*60 = 21,600 to 12*60*60 = 43200)

Comment: To clarify, you are specifically looking to make a LIST of the dictionaries? Or are you looking to place all the individual IP-time mappings into a list?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for list of dictionaries. each dictionary contain keys (ipaddress) and values preapred into a list for each ipaddress.

Comment: something like that [{'10.0.0.155': ['19:48:46', '20:15:46', '19:49:37', '20:15:08', '19:48:46', '19:47:30', '19:49:13', '20:15:50', '19:45:34', '19:45:33', '19:49:13', '19:49:16', '19:49:36', '19:50:02', '19:54:25', '20:15:06', '19:45:25', '20:15:49', '19:55:10', '19:47:33']}, {'0.0.0.0': ['00:42:43', '00:25:06', '22:37:04', '00:43:02', '00:42:58', '00:41:26', '00:42:57', '22:37:08', '00:43:01', '00:43:13', '00:43:11', '00:43:09', '00:42:14', '00:43:12', '00:42:44', '00:42:59', '00:43:10', '00:42:49', '00:42:29', '00:25:36', '00:43:03', '00:42:25', '00:25:27']}]

Comment: Is this clear to you now?

Comment: Yes. Understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Convert the `mhist` dictionaries into a `List` of the dictionaries.

```
mhist, mhist1, mhist2, mhist3, mhist4 = {}, {}, {}, {}, {}
mhist_list = [mhist, mhist1, mhist2, mhist3, mhist4]
```

Now, the dictionaries are in a `List`.

2. Now, we have a list containing 5 dictionaries and we also have 5 `if`'s. This can be used to shrink the code into a `for`-loop as requested.

```
for line in reader:   
    
        i+=1
        
        sec= line [10]
        IpAddress = line [2]
        timeStamp = line [6]
        time = timeStamp[11:13]+ timeStamp[13:19]
        Day =  timeStamp[0:10]
        
        if i>1:
            for x in range(1,6):
                if float(line[10]) <= float(x * 21600):
                    if IpAddress in mhist_list[x-1].keys():
                        mhist_list[x-1][IpAddress].append(str(time))
                    else:
                        mhist_list[x-1][IpAddress] = [str(time)]

        n+=1
```

3. Printing `mhist_list` should now give you the dictionaries as a `List`.

```
print(mhist_list)
```

This should work now.

Comment: I am trying a sample series of data and am getting your expected output with this code.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I am looking to reduce the number of lines in the code and don't need to add the dictionaries into a list manually

Comment: Ok. I will fix this now. I thought that was what you meant. Give me a little more time. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: You will find a lot of repetition lines in to my code. I want to reduce the number of lines codes .\

Comment: I know exactly what you are talking about. I'll be back soon with the answer.

Comment: You can see this part of my code has been repeated many times f float(line[10]) > float(64800) and float(line[10]) <= float(86400) :
                if IpAddress in mhist3.keys():
                    mhist3[IpAddress].append(str(time))
                else:
                    mhist3[IpAddress] = [str (time)]

Comment: I want this part of my code repeat only one time with filtration of the data every 6 hours (6 *60*60)

Comment: Ok. I made a modified solution. Let me know if it works.

Comment: To filter the data we can two different format, for example, the first one is "float(line[10]) <= float(21600)" and second one is "float(line[10]) > float(21600) and float(line[10]) <= float(43200)". In 
 your code, if we take x = 2, this means that "if float(line[10]) <= float(43200):"  and this is not matching to the format above (please check my code again).

Comment: Also, the number of dictionaries are unknow. I just give you they are 5 dictionary (mhist, mhist1, mhist2, mhist3, mhist4), but they are more than 5 dictionaries so I told you to define one dictionary into the for-loop because the number of dictionaries are unknow. As time is unknow are well. I made filtration for each 6 hours, but the total number of hours are unknow. I would be happy if you can help me in get a code can work for any case

Comment: Also, I tested your code and got this error "could not convert string to float: 'seconds'"